# error instaling grub-efi-ia32

Tags: linux, grub

I was folowing [this guide](http://hwswbits.blogspot.com/2015/03/getting-linux-on-minix-neo-z64.html) to install linux(xubuntu) on my minix neo z64, but I arrived to a part where I had to install grub-efi-ia32, but when I runned the comand to install it, it said that I nedded grub-efi-amd64-signed(or grub-efi-arm64-signed, but this is an x86_64 computer), that was already instaled(and the right version) I tried deleting and reinstaling amd64 and to install ia32 using the deb package, but it didn't work

Also during the instalation I got an error while instaling chromium-browser-|10n, I am not sure if this is relevant

Comment: You need to use a 64-bit bootloader. You are aware that AMD64 and x86_64 is exactly these something right?

Comment: @Ramhound, I realized that I botted into what I think is the flash drive(I think), I cherroted into the drive in my computer, but I got an erro because of chromium. I am downloading regular Ubuntu to see if it will work this way

Comment: You mentioned receiving an error but failed to mention the actual error.  I go back top the fact, you are being told you need to use an 64-bit EFI bootloader. Most processors in 2014 did not support both 32-bit and 64-bit bootloaders, it was a huge problem,  when the processor technically was 64-bit but ultimately could not support a 64-bit OS